# Hamburger Icon and Overflow Menu Size

Tags: codenameone

How do I control the sizes of the hamburger and overflow menu icons? What UIIDs do I need to edit to reduce the sizes.

I have checked the UIID list but can't seem to get it to reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `menuImageSize` theme constant which is currently set to 4.5. You can set it to a double positive value in millimeters.

I'll add support for an equivalent `overflowImageSize` with the same settings for the next update.